# Django 1.9 login form.is_valid freaks out

Tags: python, django, forms

I've got a strange problem here. I have a user u=filip pw=filip123

The form returns false when I type in the correct user details BUT when I reverse the typing (typing in password in the username field and username in pw field) the form.is_valid() returns true.

The request.POST gets the right value

views.py

```
def login(request):
    msg = "Login"
    form = LoginForm(request.POST)
    print (request.POST.get("username"))
    print (request.POST.get("password"))
    if form.is_valid():
        msg = "valid"
        print ("asdfa")
        user = authenticate(username=request.POST.get("username"), password=request.POST.get("password"))
        print (user)
    context = {
        "msg":msg,
        "form": form,
    }
    return render(request, "login.html", context)
```

forms.py

```
class LoginForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = [
        "username",
        "password"
    ]
```

login.html

```
{% block content %}

    {% if form.errors %}
        <p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
        {{ form.errors }}
    {% endif %}
    <h1 style="color:red">{{ msg }}</h1>
    <form method="post" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        username<input type="username" name="username">
        password<input type="password" name="password">
       <input type="submit" value="login" />
   </form>

{% endblock %}
```

edit, the error message when I'm typing in a real user is "Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.
username
A user with that username already exists."

Comment: Why would you expect it not to be valid? All you've done is validate the fields, you haven't validated if they're correct credentials

Comment: @Sayse but the form shall be valid what ever if I type in a real user or just a fake user. Currently its just validating when I'm typing in a fake user.

Answer (score 3):

This is not the right use for a ModelForm. They are for creating and editing items in the database; the error message is because you have used this form as if you were creating a new user, and it's preventing you from doing that because the user with that username already exists.

Use a standard form instead. Or even better, use the LoginForm from django.contrib.auth.forms; the advantage of that is that it calls authenticate for you as part of the validation process, so that login errors will be included in the form errors (rather than completely ignored, as your code does).